# How to use union type as property name of interface/type

Tags: typescript, types, interface

I have a union type:

```
type Browser = 'chrome' | 'firefox'
```

and I want to create an interface/type where the valid properties can only be chrome and firefox. I came up with this:

```
type IM {
  [key in Browser]: {
    string: boolean
  }
}
```

The problem is that I want allow any property within the `chrome` and `firefox` properties. Is it possible? I was trying to use bracket notion:

```
[string]: boolean
```

But unsurprisingly doesn't work.

Comment: type Browser = 'chrome' | 'firefox' | string;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to allow any `boolean` property you can use an index signature:

```
type Browser = 'chrome' | 'firefox'

type IM = {
  [key in Browser]: {
    [name: string]: boolean
  }
}
```

The custom mapped type is not really necessary, you can use `Record` instead:

```
type IM = Record<Browser, {
    [name: string]: boolean
}>
```